# Windows Form Application - MySQL - Cannot convert from 'string'

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm fairly new to the C# Language along side using tutorials to help better understand I have come across the following when trying to make a simple 'button' that makes a connection to a MySQL database.

I have installed the MySQL Connector .NET 6.9.6 reference and the MySQL Connector for ODBC (5.3.4) within Visual Studio 2013 but get the following errors:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter.MySqlDataAdapter(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand)'
>   has some invalid arguments.
>
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string'to
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand'

and not sure how to rectify them could someone point me in the right direction? I've done some research but haven't seem to have found the answer.

My code is as follows:

```
            try
             {
                 string mySqlConnection = "datasource=db;port=3306;username=usr;password=Pswd";
                 MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection (mySqlConnection);
                 MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter (mySqlConnection);
                 myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand (" Select * database.edata ;", mySqlConn);
                 MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder (myDataAdapter);
                 mySqlConn.Open();
                 DataSet ds = new DataSet ();
                 MessageBox.Show("Connected to Database");
                 mySqlConn.Close();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                      MessageBox.Show (ex.Message);
                 }
         }
```

I've substitute the correct connection details for obvious reasons, and connecting to a remote MySQL server not a local one.

Comment: should be `select * from database.edata;`. maybe other issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use your connection string in your `MySqlDataAdapter` constructor. You need to use your command instead with or without your connection. Like;

```
MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection (mySqlConnection);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from database.edata");
cmd.Connection = mySqlConn;
MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Looks like it does not have a constructor that takes `string` as a parameter but it has  `MySqlCommand` one. By the way, you forget `FROM` part in your sql query.

And don't forget to use `using` statement to dispose your connections, commands and adwapter automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.